# Incompatible Types - TArray<System.Byte> & Byte

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have declared `outputBuffer` as a `Byte` and used it accordingly:

> TFile.WriteAllBytes(outputPath, outputBuffer);

When I compile my program, Delphi outputs:

> [DCC Error] StormLib.pas(56): E2010 Incompatible types: 'System.TArray[System.Byte] and 'Byte'

Have I used the wrong/out-dated data type for my variable? What must I do to get my program to compile?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: `TFile.WriteAllBytes(outputPath, TBytes.Create(outputBuffer))` will write your 1 byte file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`TBytes`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.TBytes) instead. The [`WriteAllBytes`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.WriteAllBytes) method takes `TBytes` which is defined as `TArray<Byte>` and so is an array of bytes, not just a single `Byte`.

```
var
  OutputPath: string;
  OutputBuffer: TBytes;
begin
  // use SetLength to set the length of your OutputBuffer
  // byte array, fill it somehow and then call WriteAllBytes
  TFile.WriteAllBytes(OutputPath, OutputBuffer);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You error message clearly shows that incompatible types are not Byte and Byte, but TArray<Byte> and Byte.  Frankly - that is what expected. Array of bytes is much more than single byte.

Make variable of TArray<Byte> type and use it to contain the value.